# SVG with width/height doesn't scale on IE9/10/11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

There's a known issue with IE 9/10/11 where if you have an SVG file where the `<svg>` element specifies a width and height, and then you scale the SVG image using the `width` and `height` attributes of an `<img>` tag, IE doesn't properly scale the image.

I've run into this issue.  I have a series of SVG flag icons.  For the US flag icon, the SVG object is written as:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="480" width="640">

<!-- elements to draw flag .. -->

</svg>
```

[And here's the full source for the SVG.](http://jsfiddle.net/9pt8ze73/)

I insert the SVG into an HTML document with an `<img>` tag, and down-scale it to 20x15:

On Chrome 39, the SVG is rendered properly like so:

[image]

But on IE10, it renders as follows:

[image]

So, what seems to be happening here is that even though IE10 sizes the `<img>` element to 20x15, it doesn't downscale the SVG - so we end up seeing just the top-left corner of the flag icon, which appears as a plain blue box.

Okay... so this seems to be a known issue with [**documented solutions**](https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/7881691).  One solution is to simply remove all the `width` and `height` attributes in the SVG file.  This seems a bit dangerous as I don't want to screw up the actual designs.  It's also a bit cumbersome to do if you have a lot of SVG files - requiring more scripts to process the files.

A nicer solution is to use CSS to specifically target SVG elements in IE10, which apparently is possible using a vendor specific media query:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  img[src*=".svg"] {
    width: 100%; 
  }
}
```

Okay, but I don't understand this solution.  When I try the above, IE10 simply expands the size of the SVG to fill the entire parent container, which isn't what I want.  Okay, so maybe I can force IE to scale the SVG by setting the SVG width to 100%, but then constraining the size of the parent container.  So I wrapped the `<img>` in a DIV with a width and height of 20x15.  But... that just resulted in the same problem as before: the container DIV is fixed at 20x15, but the SVG doesn't shrink - so all we end up with is the top-left blue corner of the flag as before:

[image]

... so, I'm probably just not understanding something about this solution.  How can I get IE10/11 to scale the flag icon down to 20x15?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This happens when your image is missing the `viewBox` attribute on the `svg` element.

Yours should be set to: `0 0 640 480`.  The zeros are X and Y offsets and the 640 and 480 correspond to the width and height.  It defines a rectangle that represents the boundaries of the image.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="480" width="640" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
```

Comment: There is a good article [here](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) about it, it covers both techniques mentioned here but the one from Josiah should work

Comment: I assumed this was an either/or answer, but actually you need BOTH the `viewBox` and the CSS `width: 100%` for it to work.

Comment: specifying `height` and `width` does the trick! (aside from being mentioned in `viewBox`)

Answer (score 35):

**Take the height and width out of the SVG tag line.**

IE9, IE10, and IE11 don't properly scale SVG files added with img tags when viewBox, width and height attributes are specified.

The issue can be resolved by removing **just the `width` and `height` attributes** and manipulate them via CSS only.

```
img[src*=".svg"] {
  width: 100%; 
}
```

**Note**: If you are placing the SVG inline in IE11, then the width and height attributes are needed in the SVG tag, along with setting the width of the SVG tag to 100% using CSS, so that it scales correctly.

Comment: this solved my problem. just want to add that the "viewBox" - attr should not be removed

Comment: What if I want to use less then 100% for my images? Another words, I want to "scale" it.

Comment: @Mark You would probably scale the surrounding container.

Comment: Note that if you are placing the SVG inline in IE11, then the width and height attributes are needed in the svg tag, along with setting the width of the svg tag to 100% using css, so that it scales correctly.

Comment: Marian ... thanks for the note ... I'll add it to my answer, but also realize that this answer is over four years old.

Answer (score 2):

here is the node script i had to write to fix the same issue (for the folder with a number of SVG's), maybe it will be helpful for someone:

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs')

fs.readdir(`./`, (err, flist) => {
    if (typeof flist != 'undefined') {
        flist.forEach((file, i) => {
            proceed(file)
        })
    }
})

function proceed(file){
    fs.readFile(`./${file}`, 'utf8', (err,svg) => {
        let out = svg.replace('<svg', '<svg viewBox="0 0 640 480" ')
        if (!svg.includes('viewBox')){
            fs.writeFile(file, out, err => {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Saved: " + file);
                }
            }) 
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look @ this flag from wonderflags for your answer, you need to set viewbox="0 0 640 480" or it won't work. (EU Flag)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="480" width="640" viewBox="0 0 640 480"><defs><g id="d"><g id="b"><path d="M0-1l-.3 1h.5z" id="a"/><use transform="scale(-1 1)" xlink:href="#a"/></g><g id="c"><use transform="rotate(72)" xlink:href="#b"/><use transform="rotate(144)" xlink:href="#b"/></g><use transform="scale(-1 1)" xlink:href="#c"/></g></defs><path fill="#039" d="M0 0h640v480H0z"/><g transform="translate(320 242.263) scale(23.7037)" fill="#fc0"><use height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="#d" y="-6"/><use height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="#d" y="6"/><g id="e"><use height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="#d" x="-6"/><use height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(-144 -2.344 -2.11)"/><use height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(144 -2.11 -2.344)"/><use height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(72 -4.663 -2.076)"/><use xlink:href="#d" transform="rotate(72 -5.076 .534)"/></g><use height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="#e" transform="scale(-1 1)"/></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a lot of trouble with an inline SVG with boostrap img-fluid. The SVG was always getting rendered with the wrong height. I used the code bellow to fix it. Tested in IE10 and IE11.

```css
    @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        svg.img-fluid {
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
```