# Why do inline-block svgs overlap in Edge browser, shows small in IE11, with height in pixels and width auto?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I have two svgs which I want to show in one line. I have set them `inline-block`. They have a given height in pixels and width is set to `auto`. They render correctly in all browsers except Edge and IE11. In Edge the svgs overlap and in IE11 they don't respect the height applied. Since I can't add more than 3000 lines I have added two svgs with jquery. The same bug exists without jquery(jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yxjrvv37/)).

Demo:

```js
$(".marquee-content").clone().appendTo($(".marquee-wrapper"));
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.marquee-vertical {
  height: 200px;
}

.marquee-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

.marquee {
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.marquee-horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.marquee-horizontal .marquee-content,
.marquee-horizontal .marquee-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="marquee marquee-horizontal">
    <div class="marquee-wrapper">
      <div class="marquee-content">
        <svg style="height: 26px; width: auto;" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 526.6 28.3" xml:space="preserve">
          <style type="text/css">
            .st0 {
              fill: none;
            }
            
            .st1 {
              enable-background: new;
            }
            
            .st2 {
              fill: #009444;
            }

          </style>
          <rect y="2.3" class="st0" width="526.6" height="26"></rect>
          <g class="st1">
            <path class="st2" d="M7.2,20.8c-1.9,0-3.3-0.6-4.3-1.7s-1.5-2.8-1.5-4.9c0-2.1,0.5-3.8,1.6-5s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8
c0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.9,0.2s1.1,0.3,1.5,0.5L10,9.8C9.6,9.6,9.1,9.5,8.6,9.4s-1-0.2-1.3-0.2c-2.6,0-3.9,1.7-3.9,5c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,1,3.6
s1.6,1.3,2.8,1.3c1.1,0,2.2-0.2,3.3-0.7v1.7C9.6,20.6,8.5,20.8,7.2,20.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M24.6,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5
c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S24.6,12.1,24.6,14.1z M14.8,14.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8
s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3S14.8,12.5,14.8,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M36.8,20.6v-8.3c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.2-0.8-2.2-0.8c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.6v6.7H28V7.7h1.6
l0.3,1.8H30c0.4-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.5s1.5-0.5,2.4-0.5c1.5,0,2.7,0.4,3.5,1.1s1.2,1.9,1.2,3.6v8.4H36.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M46.9,19.2c0.3,0,0.7,0,1-0.1s0.6-0.1,0.8-0.2v1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.3s-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.1
c-2.5,0-3.7-1.3-3.7-3.9V9.2H41V8.3l1.8-0.8l0.8-2.7h1.1v3h3.7v1.5h-3.7v7.6c0,0.8,0.2,1.4,0.6,1.8S46.2,19.2,46.9,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M59.1,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5C52.3,8.3,53,8,53.7,7.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H59.1z M54.7,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S53.9,19.2,54.7,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M69.7,20.8c-1.9,0-3.3-0.6-4.3-1.7s-1.5-2.8-1.5-4.9c0-2.1,0.5-3.8,1.6-5s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8
c0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.9,0.2s1.1,0.3,1.5,0.5l-0.6,1.7c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.4-0.4s-1-0.2-1.3-0.2c-2.6,0-3.9,1.7-3.9,5
c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,1,3.6s1.6,1.3,2.8,1.3c1.1,0,2.2-0.2,3.3-0.7v1.7C72.1,20.6,71,20.8,69.7,20.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M80.1,19.2c0.3,0,0.7,0,1-0.1s0.6-0.1,0.8-0.2v1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.3s-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.1
c-2.5,0-3.7-1.3-3.7-3.9V9.2h-1.8V8.3l1.8-0.8l0.8-2.7H78v3h3.7v1.5H78v7.6c0,0.8,0.2,1.4,0.6,1.8S79.5,19.2,80.1,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M95.5,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5
c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S95.5,12.1,95.5,14.1z M85.7,14.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8
s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3S85.7,12.5,85.7,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M107.7,24.3H96.8v-1.5h10.9V24.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M118.5,20.6v-8.3c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.2-0.8-2.2-0.8c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.6v6.7h-1.9V7.7
h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1c0.4-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.5s1.5-0.5,2.4-0.5c1.5,0,2.7,0.4,3.5,1.1s1.2,1.9,1.2,3.6v8.4H118.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M135.5,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3
s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S135.5,12.1,135.5,14.1z M125.7,14.1
c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3
S125.7,12.5,125.7,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M147.7,24.3h-10.9v-1.5h10.9V24.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M158,17.1c0,1.2-0.4,2.1-1.3,2.8s-2.1,1-3.8,1c-1.7,0-3-0.3-4-0.8v-1.8c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.6,2,0.7s1.4,0.3,2,0.3
c1,0,1.8-0.2,2.3-0.5s0.8-0.8,0.8-1.5c0-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.7-1.3s-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.3c-1.2-0.4-2-0.8-2.5-1.2s-0.9-0.7-1.1-1.1
s-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.5c0-1,0.4-1.9,1.3-2.5s2-0.9,3.5-0.9c1.4,0,2.7,0.3,4.1,0.8L157,9.9c-1.3-0.5-2.5-0.8-3.5-0.8
c-0.9,0-1.6,0.1-2.1,0.4s-0.7,0.7-0.7,1.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.7s1.1,0.5,2.3,0.9c1.5,0.6,2.6,1.1,3.1,1.7
S158,16.2,158,17.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M167.1,20.8c-0.8,0-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5s-1.3-0.8-1.7-1.4h-0.1c0.1,0.8,0.1,1.5,0.1,2.1v5.3h-1.9V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8
h0.1c0.5-0.7,1.1-1.2,1.7-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.3-0.5c1.7,0,3,0.6,3.9,1.7s1.4,2.8,1.4,4.9c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.4,4.9S168.8,20.8,167.1,20.8z
M166.8,9.1c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-2.8,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.5v0.4c0,1.8,0.3,3.1,0.9,3.9s1.6,1.2,2.9,1.2c1.1,0,2-0.4,2.6-1.3
s0.9-2.1,0.9-3.7c0-1.6-0.3-2.8-0.9-3.7S168,9.1,166.8,9.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M183.7,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H183.7z M179.3,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S178.6,19.2,179.3,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M205.5,20.6v-8.4c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.3-2.7,1s-0.9,1.8-0.9,3.2v7.2h-1.9v-8.4
c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2.1-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.7,1.1s-0.8,1.9-0.8,3.6v6.7h-1.9V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.4-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.6-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.2-0.5c2,0,3.3,0.7,3.9,2.2h0.1c0.4-0.7,0.9-1.2,1.7-1.6s1.6-0.6,2.5-0.6c1.5,0,2.5,0.4,3.3,1.1
s1.1,1.9,1.1,3.6v8.4H205.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M220.9,10l-0.8,4h3.3v1.5h-3.6l-1,5h-1.6l1-5h-3.6l-1,5h-1.6l0.9-5H210V14h3.4l0.8-4h-3.2V8.5h3.5l1-5.1h1.6
l-1,5.1h3.6l1-5.1h1.6l-1,5.1h3.1V10H220.9z M215,14h3.6l0.8-4h-3.6L215,14z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M229.8,20.6l-4.9-12.8h2.1l2.8,7.6c0.6,1.8,1,2.9,1.1,3.5h0.1c0.1-0.4,0.4-1.3,0.8-2.6s1.5-4.1,3.1-8.5h2.1
l-4.9,12.8H229.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M244.5,20.8c-1.9,0-3.4-0.6-4.5-1.7s-1.6-2.8-1.6-4.8c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.5-4.9s2.4-1.8,4.1-1.8
c1.6,0,2.9,0.5,3.8,1.6s1.4,2.5,1.4,4.2v1.2h-8.8c0,1.5,0.4,2.7,1.1,3.4s1.7,1.2,3.1,1.2c1.4,0,2.8-0.3,4.1-0.9V20
c-0.7,0.3-1.3,0.5-2,0.6S245.3,20.8,244.5,20.8z M243.9,9.1c-1,0-1.9,0.3-2.5,1s-1,1.6-1.1,2.8h6.7c0-1.2-0.3-2.2-0.8-2.8
S244.9,9.1,243.9,9.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M261.3,20.6v-8.3c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.2-0.8-2.2-0.8c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.6v6.7h-1.9V7.7
h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1c0.4-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.5s1.5-0.5,2.4-0.5c1.5,0,2.7,0.4,3.5,1.1s1.2,1.9,1.2,3.6v8.4H261.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M271.4,19.2c0.3,0,0.7,0,1-0.1s0.6-0.1,0.8-0.2v1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.3s-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.1
c-2.5,0-3.7-1.3-3.7-3.9V9.2h-1.8V8.3l1.8-0.8l0.8-2.7h1.1v3h3.7v1.5h-3.7v7.6c0,0.8,0.2,1.4,0.6,1.8S270.7,19.2,271.4,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M283.6,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H283.6z M279.2,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S278.4,19.2,279.2,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M295,20.8c-0.8,0-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5s-1.3-0.8-1.7-1.4h-0.1c0.1,0.8,0.1,1.5,0.1,2.1v5.3H289V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.5-0.7,1.1-1.2,1.7-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.3-0.5c1.7,0,3,0.6,3.9,1.7s1.4,2.8,1.4,4.9c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.4,4.9S296.7,20.8,295,20.8z
M294.7,9.1c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-2.8,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.5v0.4c0,1.8,0.3,3.1,0.9,3.9s1.6,1.2,2.9,1.2c1.1,0,2-0.4,2.6-1.3
s0.9-2.1,0.9-3.7c0-1.6-0.3-2.8-0.9-3.7S295.9,9.1,294.7,9.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M303.6,4.2c0-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.3-1s0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3s0.3,0.5,0.3,1s-0.1,0.8-0.3,1
s-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3S303.6,4.7,303.6,4.2z M305.7,20.6h-1.9V7.7h1.9V20.6z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M318.1,17.1c0,1.2-0.4,2.1-1.3,2.8s-2.1,1-3.8,1c-1.7,0-3-0.3-4-0.8v-1.8c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.6,2,0.7s1.4,0.3,2,0.3
c1,0,1.8-0.2,2.3-0.5s0.8-0.8,0.8-1.5c0-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.7-1.3s-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.3c-1.2-0.4-2-0.8-2.5-1.2s-0.9-0.7-1.1-1.1
s-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.5c0-1,0.4-1.9,1.3-2.5s2-0.9,3.5-0.9c1.4,0,2.7,0.3,4.1,0.8l-0.7,1.6c-1.3-0.5-2.5-0.8-3.5-0.8
c-0.9,0-1.6,0.1-2.1,0.4s-0.7,0.7-0.7,1.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.7s1.1,0.5,2.3,0.9c1.5,0.6,2.6,1.1,3.1,1.7
S318.1,16.2,318.1,17.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M332.4,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3
s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S332.4,12.1,332.4,14.1z M322.6,14.1
c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3
S322.6,12.5,322.6,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M346.3,7.7V9l-2.4,0.3c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,1.1s0.3,0.9,0.3,1.5c0,1.3-0.4,2.3-1.3,3s-2,1.1-3.5,1.1
c-0.4,0-0.7,0-1.1-0.1c-0.8,0.4-1.2,1-1.2,1.7c0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.8s0.8,0.3,1.5,0.3h2.3c1.4,0,2.5,0.3,3.2,0.9s1.1,1.4,1.1,2.6
c0,1.4-0.6,2.5-1.7,3.3s-2.8,1.1-5,1.1c-1.7,0-3-0.3-3.9-0.9s-1.4-1.5-1.4-2.6c0-0.8,0.3-1.5,0.8-2s1.2-1,2.1-1.2
c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.4-0.8-0.7s-0.3-0.7-0.3-1.1c0-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.4-1.2s0.6-0.7,1.2-1c-0.7-0.3-1.2-0.7-1.6-1.4s-0.6-1.4-0.6-2.3
c0-1.4,0.4-2.5,1.3-3.3s2-1.1,3.6-1.1c0.7,0,1.3,0.1,1.8,0.2H346.3z M336,22.7c0,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.9,1.6s1.4,0.5,2.5,0.5
c1.6,0,2.8-0.2,3.6-0.7s1.2-1.2,1.2-2c0-0.7-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.4s-1.2-0.4-2.4-0.4h-2.3c-0.9,0-1.6,0.2-2.1,0.6S336,21.9,336,22.7z
M337.1,11.8c0,0.9,0.3,1.6,0.8,2s1.2,0.7,2.1,0.7c1.9,0,2.8-0.9,2.8-2.8c0-1.9-1-2.9-2.9-2.9c-0.9,0-1.6,0.2-2.1,0.7
S337.1,10.9,337.1,11.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M350.7,7.7v8.3c0,1,0.2,1.8,0.7,2.3s1.2,0.8,2.2,0.8c1.3,0,2.3-0.4,2.9-1.1s0.9-1.9,0.9-3.6V7.7h1.9v12.8h-1.6
l-0.3-1.7h-0.1c-0.4,0.6-1,1.1-1.7,1.5s-1.5,0.5-2.4,0.5c-1.6,0-2.7-0.4-3.5-1.1s-1.2-1.9-1.2-3.6V7.7H350.7z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M371.5,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H371.5z M367.1,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S366.4,19.2,367.1,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M385.7,18.8h-0.1c-0.9,1.3-2.2,2-4,2c-1.7,0-3-0.6-3.9-1.7s-1.4-2.8-1.4-4.9s0.5-3.8,1.4-4.9s2.2-1.8,3.9-1.8
c1.7,0,3.1,0.6,4,1.9h0.2l-0.1-0.9l0-0.9V2.3h1.9v18.2H386L385.7,18.8z M381.8,19.2c1.3,0,2.3-0.4,2.9-1.1s0.9-1.9,0.9-3.5v-0.4
c0-1.8-0.3-3.1-0.9-3.9s-1.6-1.2-2.9-1.2c-1.1,0-2,0.4-2.6,1.3s-0.9,2.1-0.9,3.8c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,0.9,3.7S380.7,19.2,381.8,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M399.6,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H399.6z M395.2,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S394.4,19.2,395.2,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M410.9,7.5c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.5,0.1l-0.3,1.8c-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.4-0.2c-1,0-1.9,0.4-2.7,1.3s-1.1,1.9-1.1,3.2v6.9
H405V7.7h1.6l0.2,2.4h0.1c0.5-0.8,1.1-1.5,1.7-1.9S410.1,7.5,410.9,7.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M420.7,7.5c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.5,0.1L422,9.4c-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.4-0.2c-1,0-1.9,0.4-2.7,1.3s-1.1,1.9-1.1,3.2v6.9
h-1.9V7.7h1.6l0.2,2.4h0.1c0.5-0.8,1.1-1.5,1.7-1.9S419.9,7.5,420.7,7.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M432.5,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H432.5z M428.1,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S427.4,19.2,428.1,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M454.4,20.6v-8.4c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.3-2.7,1s-0.9,1.8-0.9,3.2v7.2h-1.9v-8.4
c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2.1-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.7,1.1s-0.8,1.9-0.8,3.6v6.7H438V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.4-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.6-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.2-0.5c2,0,3.3,0.7,3.9,2.2h0.1c0.4-0.7,0.9-1.2,1.7-1.6s1.6-0.6,2.5-0.6c1.5,0,2.5,0.4,3.3,1.1
s1.1,1.9,1.1,3.6v8.4H454.4z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M468.2,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2S466,9.1,465,9.1c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H468.2z M463.8,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S463.1,19.2,463.8,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M473.4,19.3c0-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.4-1.2s0.6-0.4,1-0.4c0.5,0,0.8,0.1,1.1,0.4s0.4,0.7,0.4,1.2
c0,0.5-0.1,0.9-0.4,1.2s-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.4S473.4,19.9,473.4,19.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M485.2,20.8c-1.9,0-3.3-0.6-4.3-1.7s-1.5-2.8-1.5-4.9c0-2.1,0.5-3.8,1.6-5s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8
c0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.9,0.2s1.1,0.3,1.5,0.5L488,9.8c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.4-0.4s-1-0.2-1.3-0.2c-2.6,0-3.9,1.7-3.9,5
c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,1,3.6s1.6,1.3,2.8,1.3c1.1,0,2.2-0.2,3.3-0.7v1.7C487.6,20.6,486.5,20.8,485.2,20.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M502.6,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3
s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S502.6,12.1,502.6,14.1z M492.8,14.1
c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3
S492.8,12.5,492.8,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M522.3,20.6v-8.4c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.3-2.7,1s-0.9,1.8-0.9,3.2v7.2h-1.9v-8.4
c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2.1-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.7,1.1s-0.8,1.9-0.8,3.6v6.7H506V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.4-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.6-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.2-0.5c2,0,3.3,0.7,3.9,2.2h0.1c0.4-0.7,0.9-1.2,1.7-1.6s1.6-0.6,2.5-0.6c1.5,0,2.5,0.4,3.3,1.1
s1.1,1.9,1.1,3.6v8.4H522.3z"></path>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you open this demo in Edge browser you'd see the svgs overlapping each other and in IE11 height is not applied properly to svgs. But this doesn't happen in any other browser?

1. Why do in Edge browser the svgs overlap?
2. Why is in IE11 inline height not applied correctly?

**Proof:**

Edge version:       38.14393
Edge Html version:  14.14393

Windows 10 Pro
OS Version: 1115
OS Build: 10586.839

[image]

Comment: As I found the bug is due to height in pixels and auto width not due to jquery I have corrected the question.

Comment: edge tested. works Ok.

Comment: @SagarV I added the image of Edge browser. Can you show your image where it works ok?

Comment: there you go https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDQnk.png

Comment: @SagarV May be its with my Edge version only. I am using Edge 38.14393 having EdgeHtml 14.14393

Comment: anything in console ??

Comment: @SagarV Edge complains about some svg tags as _"HTML1500: Tag cannot be self-closing. Use an explicit closing tag"_ But changing them to closing pair of tags doesn't fix the rendering bug.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of console

Comment: just upload in the answer tab, copy the url and comment it here. no need to post it.

Comment: @SagarV Its strange uploading any image on imgur was giving error. But I followed your comment above.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOg6i.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139770/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-user31782).

Comment: Edge Tested: works ok.

Comment: @YochaiAkoka Try in Edge 38.14393 having EdgeHtml 14.14393

Comment: @user31782 I can also confirm that it works. http://i.imgur.com/7B8sgFo.png

Comment: @user31782 See the image I linked

Comment: [To that chat mobile!](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139770/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-user31782)

Comment: @user31782 Will the width **always** be 526.6px?

Comment: Regarding dimensions in IE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27970520/svg-with-width-height-doesnt-scale-on-ie9-10-11

Answer (score 3):

Following our [conversation in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139770/discussion-between-sagar-v-and-user31782). I have found a fix to the small text problem in IE11.

[image: IE11 small text]

The reason for this was that `.marquee-horizontal` was setting `width: 300px;` and IE11 was interpreting this for all the children. This meant your SVG had a height of 26px and a width of 300px. That was changing the aspect ratio of the image.

Providing all the sizes don't change, then add the following CSS.

```css
.marquee-content svg {
    height: 26px;
    width: 483.8px;
}
```

Obviously the downside to this is that you need explicitly set the width which is annoying.
<sub>I'll do some thinking / research on how to make the SVG keep it's aspect ratio and have a dynamic width and set height. (Using `width: auto;` works in all browsers except IE11)</sub>

### Update

**This is really irritating me.**

I have done some more playing with the code. If you change your `svg` code.
From this

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 526.6 28.3" xml:space="preserve">
```

To this

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
```

What I have changed there is to remove the `viewBox"`. This is because the [`viewBox` attribute](http://jonibologna.com/svg-viewbox-and-viewport/#viewbox) takes the parameters (separated by spaces), `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height`. So in this instance, removing these just makes the `svg` scale itself.

That will fix the "small look" of the `svg`. What this won't solve is the mysterious overlapping.
In IE the SVG will say "contacto_no_spam#ventapisoguadarrama.com" and the two SVGs will overlap.
In Chrome the SVG will say "contacto_no_spam#ventap". But if you go into developer console you can still highlight the paths, they are just invisible. Both browsers stop the width of the element right after the "ventap" bit. IE just completes the SVG, whereas other browsers don't.

I have never used `svg`s before so I don't know the reason for this. I am just trying really head because I hate not knowing.

Comment: Its a jarring bug in Internet Explorer. It takes `width: auto` same as `width: inherit` on svg.

Comment: @user31782 So the solution of setting the width doesn't work?

Comment: The real situation where I use this svg is somewhat different. The svg container have background color and the container goes as tall as much tall the svg I set. And from back end they might change the email address. This works in principle, but I'll have to tests all other browsers, set line-heights on svgs and so and so. I give up IE11 support for this case and will add a banner to the site _Use any browser other than IE_.

Comment: @user31782 On Chrome the result is "contacto_no_spam#ventap". This is the same for IE (well sort of). In IE the result is "contacto_no_spam#ventapisoguadarrama.com". Except the `.marquee-content` thinks it stops at "#ventap" and as a result they overlap. **Can you confirm what the `svg` should say?**

Comment: It should say whats it is saying in my question. What has happened when you removed the viewBox is that the path tags work as pixels and svg tags take the browser default 300x150 dimensions. The path tags exted beyond svg tag and svg has default overflow hidden.

Comment: I think I have replicated the underlying issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260129/how-to-apply-width-auto-to-svg-in-edge-and-internet-explorer-11-browsers

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure your problem is just the standard "IE-not-scaling-SVGs-properly-when-bot-width-and-height-are-not-specified" bug.

[See this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415980/svgs-not-scaling-properly-in-ie-has-extra-space)

When you update your example with the canvas fix trick from that SO entry, the page in Edge looks the same as other browsers, and IE11 looks *almost* the same.

```js
$(".marquee-content").clone().appendTo($(".marquee-wrapper"));
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.marquee-vertical {
  height: 200px;
}

.marquee-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
}

.marquee {
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.marquee-horizontal {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.marquee-horizontal .marquee-content,
.marquee-horizontal .marquee-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <div class="marquee marquee-horizontal">
    <div class="marquee-wrapper">
      <div class="marquee-content">
        <canvas width="527" height="28"></canvas>
        <svg style="height: 26px; width: auto;" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 526.6 28.3" xml:space="preserve">
          <style type="text/css">
            .st0 {
              fill: none;
            }
            
            .st1 {
              enable-background: new;
            }
            
            .st2 {
              fill: #009444;
            }

          </style>
          <rect y="2.3" class="st0" width="526.6" height="26"></rect>
          <g class="st1">
            <path class="st2" d="M7.2,20.8c-1.9,0-3.3-0.6-4.3-1.7s-1.5-2.8-1.5-4.9c0-2.1,0.5-3.8,1.6-5s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8
c0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.9,0.2s1.1,0.3,1.5,0.5L10,9.8C9.6,9.6,9.1,9.5,8.6,9.4s-1-0.2-1.3-0.2c-2.6,0-3.9,1.7-3.9,5c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,1,3.6
s1.6,1.3,2.8,1.3c1.1,0,2.2-0.2,3.3-0.7v1.7C9.6,20.6,8.5,20.8,7.2,20.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M24.6,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5
c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S24.6,12.1,24.6,14.1z M14.8,14.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8
s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3S14.8,12.5,14.8,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M36.8,20.6v-8.3c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.2-0.8-2.2-0.8c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.6v6.7H28V7.7h1.6
l0.3,1.8H30c0.4-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.5s1.5-0.5,2.4-0.5c1.5,0,2.7,0.4,3.5,1.1s1.2,1.9,1.2,3.6v8.4H36.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M46.9,19.2c0.3,0,0.7,0,1-0.1s0.6-0.1,0.8-0.2v1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.3s-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.1
c-2.5,0-3.7-1.3-3.7-3.9V9.2H41V8.3l1.8-0.8l0.8-2.7h1.1v3h3.7v1.5h-3.7v7.6c0,0.8,0.2,1.4,0.6,1.8S46.2,19.2,46.9,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M59.1,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5C52.3,8.3,53,8,53.7,7.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H59.1z M54.7,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S53.9,19.2,54.7,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M69.7,20.8c-1.9,0-3.3-0.6-4.3-1.7s-1.5-2.8-1.5-4.9c0-2.1,0.5-3.8,1.6-5s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8
c0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.9,0.2s1.1,0.3,1.5,0.5l-0.6,1.7c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.4-0.4s-1-0.2-1.3-0.2c-2.6,0-3.9,1.7-3.9,5
c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,1,3.6s1.6,1.3,2.8,1.3c1.1,0,2.2-0.2,3.3-0.7v1.7C72.1,20.6,71,20.8,69.7,20.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M80.1,19.2c0.3,0,0.7,0,1-0.1s0.6-0.1,0.8-0.2v1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.3s-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.1
c-2.5,0-3.7-1.3-3.7-3.9V9.2h-1.8V8.3l1.8-0.8l0.8-2.7H78v3h3.7v1.5H78v7.6c0,0.8,0.2,1.4,0.6,1.8S79.5,19.2,80.1,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M95.5,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5
c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S95.5,12.1,95.5,14.1z M85.7,14.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8
s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3S85.7,12.5,85.7,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M107.7,24.3H96.8v-1.5h10.9V24.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M118.5,20.6v-8.3c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.2-0.8-2.2-0.8c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.6v6.7h-1.9V7.7
h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1c0.4-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.5s1.5-0.5,2.4-0.5c1.5,0,2.7,0.4,3.5,1.1s1.2,1.9,1.2,3.6v8.4H118.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M135.5,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3
s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S135.5,12.1,135.5,14.1z M125.7,14.1
c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3
S125.7,12.5,125.7,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M147.7,24.3h-10.9v-1.5h10.9V24.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M158,17.1c0,1.2-0.4,2.1-1.3,2.8s-2.1,1-3.8,1c-1.7,0-3-0.3-4-0.8v-1.8c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.6,2,0.7s1.4,0.3,2,0.3
c1,0,1.8-0.2,2.3-0.5s0.8-0.8,0.8-1.5c0-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.7-1.3s-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.3c-1.2-0.4-2-0.8-2.5-1.2s-0.9-0.7-1.1-1.1
s-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.5c0-1,0.4-1.9,1.3-2.5s2-0.9,3.5-0.9c1.4,0,2.7,0.3,4.1,0.8L157,9.9c-1.3-0.5-2.5-0.8-3.5-0.8
c-0.9,0-1.6,0.1-2.1,0.4s-0.7,0.7-0.7,1.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.7s1.1,0.5,2.3,0.9c1.5,0.6,2.6,1.1,3.1,1.7
S158,16.2,158,17.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M167.1,20.8c-0.8,0-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5s-1.3-0.8-1.7-1.4h-0.1c0.1,0.8,0.1,1.5,0.1,2.1v5.3h-1.9V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8
h0.1c0.5-0.7,1.1-1.2,1.7-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.3-0.5c1.7,0,3,0.6,3.9,1.7s1.4,2.8,1.4,4.9c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.4,4.9S168.8,20.8,167.1,20.8z
M166.8,9.1c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-2.8,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.5v0.4c0,1.8,0.3,3.1,0.9,3.9s1.6,1.2,2.9,1.2c1.1,0,2-0.4,2.6-1.3
s0.9-2.1,0.9-3.7c0-1.6-0.3-2.8-0.9-3.7S168,9.1,166.8,9.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M183.7,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H183.7z M179.3,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S178.6,19.2,179.3,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M205.5,20.6v-8.4c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.3-2.7,1s-0.9,1.8-0.9,3.2v7.2h-1.9v-8.4
c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2.1-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.7,1.1s-0.8,1.9-0.8,3.6v6.7h-1.9V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.4-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.6-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.2-0.5c2,0,3.3,0.7,3.9,2.2h0.1c0.4-0.7,0.9-1.2,1.7-1.6s1.6-0.6,2.5-0.6c1.5,0,2.5,0.4,3.3,1.1
s1.1,1.9,1.1,3.6v8.4H205.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M220.9,10l-0.8,4h3.3v1.5h-3.6l-1,5h-1.6l1-5h-3.6l-1,5h-1.6l0.9-5H210V14h3.4l0.8-4h-3.2V8.5h3.5l1-5.1h1.6
l-1,5.1h3.6l1-5.1h1.6l-1,5.1h3.1V10H220.9z M215,14h3.6l0.8-4h-3.6L215,14z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M229.8,20.6l-4.9-12.8h2.1l2.8,7.6c0.6,1.8,1,2.9,1.1,3.5h0.1c0.1-0.4,0.4-1.3,0.8-2.6s1.5-4.1,3.1-8.5h2.1
l-4.9,12.8H229.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M244.5,20.8c-1.9,0-3.4-0.6-4.5-1.7s-1.6-2.8-1.6-4.8c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.5-4.9s2.4-1.8,4.1-1.8
c1.6,0,2.9,0.5,3.8,1.6s1.4,2.5,1.4,4.2v1.2h-8.8c0,1.5,0.4,2.7,1.1,3.4s1.7,1.2,3.1,1.2c1.4,0,2.8-0.3,4.1-0.9V20
c-0.7,0.3-1.3,0.5-2,0.6S245.3,20.8,244.5,20.8z M243.9,9.1c-1,0-1.9,0.3-2.5,1s-1,1.6-1.1,2.8h6.7c0-1.2-0.3-2.2-0.8-2.8
S244.9,9.1,243.9,9.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M261.3,20.6v-8.3c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.2-0.8-2.2-0.8c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-3,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.6v6.7h-1.9V7.7
h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1c0.4-0.6,1-1.1,1.7-1.5s1.5-0.5,2.4-0.5c1.5,0,2.7,0.4,3.5,1.1s1.2,1.9,1.2,3.6v8.4H261.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M271.4,19.2c0.3,0,0.7,0,1-0.1s0.6-0.1,0.8-0.2v1.5c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.3s-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.1
c-2.5,0-3.7-1.3-3.7-3.9V9.2h-1.8V8.3l1.8-0.8l0.8-2.7h1.1v3h3.7v1.5h-3.7v7.6c0,0.8,0.2,1.4,0.6,1.8S270.7,19.2,271.4,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M283.6,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H283.6z M279.2,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S278.4,19.2,279.2,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M295,20.8c-0.8,0-1.6-0.2-2.3-0.5s-1.3-0.8-1.7-1.4h-0.1c0.1,0.8,0.1,1.5,0.1,2.1v5.3H289V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.5-0.7,1.1-1.2,1.7-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.3-0.5c1.7,0,3,0.6,3.9,1.7s1.4,2.8,1.4,4.9c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.4,4.9S296.7,20.8,295,20.8z
M294.7,9.1c-1.3,0-2.3,0.4-2.8,1.1s-0.9,1.9-0.9,3.5v0.4c0,1.8,0.3,3.1,0.9,3.9s1.6,1.2,2.9,1.2c1.1,0,2-0.4,2.6-1.3
s0.9-2.1,0.9-3.7c0-1.6-0.3-2.8-0.9-3.7S295.9,9.1,294.7,9.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M303.6,4.2c0-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.3-1s0.5-0.3,0.8-0.3c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.8,0.3s0.3,0.5,0.3,1s-0.1,0.8-0.3,1
s-0.5,0.3-0.8,0.3c-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.8-0.3S303.6,4.7,303.6,4.2z M305.7,20.6h-1.9V7.7h1.9V20.6z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M318.1,17.1c0,1.2-0.4,2.1-1.3,2.8s-2.1,1-3.8,1c-1.7,0-3-0.3-4-0.8v-1.8c0.6,0.3,1.3,0.6,2,0.7s1.4,0.3,2,0.3
c1,0,1.8-0.2,2.3-0.5s0.8-0.8,0.8-1.5c0-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.7-1.3s-1.3-0.8-2.5-1.3c-1.2-0.4-2-0.8-2.5-1.2s-0.9-0.7-1.1-1.1
s-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.5c0-1,0.4-1.9,1.3-2.5s2-0.9,3.5-0.9c1.4,0,2.7,0.3,4.1,0.8l-0.7,1.6c-1.3-0.5-2.5-0.8-3.5-0.8
c-0.9,0-1.6,0.1-2.1,0.4s-0.7,0.7-0.7,1.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.7s1.1,0.5,2.3,0.9c1.5,0.6,2.6,1.1,3.1,1.7
S318.1,16.2,318.1,17.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M332.4,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3
s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S332.4,12.1,332.4,14.1z M322.6,14.1
c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3
S322.6,12.5,322.6,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M346.3,7.7V9l-2.4,0.3c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,1.1s0.3,0.9,0.3,1.5c0,1.3-0.4,2.3-1.3,3s-2,1.1-3.5,1.1
c-0.4,0-0.7,0-1.1-0.1c-0.8,0.4-1.2,1-1.2,1.7c0,0.4,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.8s0.8,0.3,1.5,0.3h2.3c1.4,0,2.5,0.3,3.2,0.9s1.1,1.4,1.1,2.6
c0,1.4-0.6,2.5-1.7,3.3s-2.8,1.1-5,1.1c-1.7,0-3-0.3-3.9-0.9s-1.4-1.5-1.4-2.6c0-0.8,0.3-1.5,0.8-2s1.2-1,2.1-1.2
c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.4-0.8-0.7s-0.3-0.7-0.3-1.1c0-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.4-1.2s0.6-0.7,1.2-1c-0.7-0.3-1.2-0.7-1.6-1.4s-0.6-1.4-0.6-2.3
c0-1.4,0.4-2.5,1.3-3.3s2-1.1,3.6-1.1c0.7,0,1.3,0.1,1.8,0.2H346.3z M336,22.7c0,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.9,1.6s1.4,0.5,2.5,0.5
c1.6,0,2.8-0.2,3.6-0.7s1.2-1.2,1.2-2c0-0.7-0.2-1.2-0.6-1.4s-1.2-0.4-2.4-0.4h-2.3c-0.9,0-1.6,0.2-2.1,0.6S336,21.9,336,22.7z
M337.1,11.8c0,0.9,0.3,1.6,0.8,2s1.2,0.7,2.1,0.7c1.9,0,2.8-0.9,2.8-2.8c0-1.9-1-2.9-2.9-2.9c-0.9,0-1.6,0.2-2.1,0.7
S337.1,10.9,337.1,11.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M350.7,7.7v8.3c0,1,0.2,1.8,0.7,2.3s1.2,0.8,2.2,0.8c1.3,0,2.3-0.4,2.9-1.1s0.9-1.9,0.9-3.6V7.7h1.9v12.8h-1.6
l-0.3-1.7h-0.1c-0.4,0.6-1,1.1-1.7,1.5s-1.5,0.5-2.4,0.5c-1.6,0-2.7-0.4-3.5-1.1s-1.2-1.9-1.2-3.6V7.7H350.7z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M371.5,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H371.5z M367.1,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S366.4,19.2,367.1,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M385.7,18.8h-0.1c-0.9,1.3-2.2,2-4,2c-1.7,0-3-0.6-3.9-1.7s-1.4-2.8-1.4-4.9s0.5-3.8,1.4-4.9s2.2-1.8,3.9-1.8
c1.7,0,3.1,0.6,4,1.9h0.2l-0.1-0.9l0-0.9V2.3h1.9v18.2H386L385.7,18.8z M381.8,19.2c1.3,0,2.3-0.4,2.9-1.1s0.9-1.9,0.9-3.5v-0.4
c0-1.8-0.3-3.1-0.9-3.9s-1.6-1.2-2.9-1.2c-1.1,0-2,0.4-2.6,1.3s-0.9,2.1-0.9,3.8c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,0.9,3.7S380.7,19.2,381.8,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M399.6,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H399.6z M395.2,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S394.4,19.2,395.2,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M410.9,7.5c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.5,0.1l-0.3,1.8c-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.4-0.2c-1,0-1.9,0.4-2.7,1.3s-1.1,1.9-1.1,3.2v6.9
H405V7.7h1.6l0.2,2.4h0.1c0.5-0.8,1.1-1.5,1.7-1.9S410.1,7.5,410.9,7.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M420.7,7.5c0.6,0,1.1,0,1.5,0.1L422,9.4c-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.4-0.2c-1,0-1.9,0.4-2.7,1.3s-1.1,1.9-1.1,3.2v6.9
h-1.9V7.7h1.6l0.2,2.4h0.1c0.5-0.8,1.1-1.5,1.7-1.9S419.9,7.5,420.7,7.5z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M432.5,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2s-1.1-0.7-2.1-0.7c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H432.5z M428.1,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S427.4,19.2,428.1,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M454.4,20.6v-8.4c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.3-2.7,1s-0.9,1.8-0.9,3.2v7.2h-1.9v-8.4
c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2.1-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.7,1.1s-0.8,1.9-0.8,3.6v6.7H438V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.4-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.6-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.2-0.5c2,0,3.3,0.7,3.9,2.2h0.1c0.4-0.7,0.9-1.2,1.7-1.6s1.6-0.6,2.5-0.6c1.5,0,2.5,0.4,3.3,1.1
s1.1,1.9,1.1,3.6v8.4H454.4z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M468.2,20.6l-0.4-1.8h-0.1c-0.6,0.8-1.3,1.3-1.9,1.6s-1.4,0.4-2.4,0.4c-1.3,0-2.3-0.3-3-1s-1.1-1.6-1.1-2.8
c0-2.6,2.1-4,6.2-4.1l2.2-0.1v-0.8c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.2S466,9.1,465,9.1c-1.1,0-2.3,0.3-3.6,1l-0.6-1.5c0.6-0.3,1.3-0.6,2.1-0.8
s1.5-0.3,2.3-0.3c1.5,0,2.7,0.3,3.4,1s1.1,1.8,1.1,3.3v8.8H468.2z M463.8,19.2c1.2,0,2.2-0.3,2.9-1s1-1.6,1-2.8v-1.2l-1.9,0.1
c-1.5,0.1-2.7,0.3-3.3,0.7s-1,1.1-1,2c0,0.7,0.2,1.2,0.6,1.6S463.1,19.2,463.8,19.2z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M473.4,19.3c0-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.4-1.2s0.6-0.4,1-0.4c0.5,0,0.8,0.1,1.1,0.4s0.4,0.7,0.4,1.2
c0,0.5-0.1,0.9-0.4,1.2s-0.6,0.4-1.1,0.4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.4S473.4,19.9,473.4,19.3z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M485.2,20.8c-1.9,0-3.3-0.6-4.3-1.7s-1.5-2.8-1.5-4.9c0-2.1,0.5-3.8,1.6-5s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8
c0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.9,0.2s1.1,0.3,1.5,0.5L488,9.8c-0.4-0.2-0.9-0.3-1.4-0.4s-1-0.2-1.3-0.2c-2.6,0-3.9,1.7-3.9,5
c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,1,3.6s1.6,1.3,2.8,1.3c1.1,0,2.2-0.2,3.3-0.7v1.7C487.6,20.6,486.5,20.8,485.2,20.8z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M502.6,14.1c0,2.1-0.5,3.7-1.6,4.9s-2.5,1.8-4.4,1.8c-1.1,0-2.2-0.3-3.1-0.8s-1.6-1.3-2.1-2.3
s-0.7-2.2-0.7-3.5c0-2.1,0.5-3.7,1.6-4.9s2.5-1.8,4.4-1.8c1.8,0,3.2,0.6,4.3,1.8S502.6,12.1,502.6,14.1z M492.8,14.1
c0,1.6,0.3,2.9,1,3.8s1.6,1.3,2.9,1.3s2.2-0.4,2.9-1.3s1-2.1,1-3.8c0-1.6-0.3-2.9-1-3.7s-1.6-1.3-2.9-1.3c-1.3,0-2.2,0.4-2.9,1.3
S492.8,12.5,492.8,14.1z"></path>
            <path class="st2" d="M522.3,20.6v-8.4c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.3-2.7,1s-0.9,1.8-0.9,3.2v7.2h-1.9v-8.4
c0-1-0.2-1.8-0.7-2.3s-1.1-0.8-2.1-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.7,1.1s-0.8,1.9-0.8,3.6v6.7H506V7.7h1.6l0.3,1.8h0.1
c0.4-0.6,0.9-1.1,1.6-1.5s1.4-0.5,2.2-0.5c2,0,3.3,0.7,3.9,2.2h0.1c0.4-0.7,0.9-1.2,1.7-1.6s1.6-0.6,2.5-0.6c1.5,0,2.5,0.4,3.3,1.1
s1.1,1.9,1.1,3.6v8.4H522.3z"></path>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With canvas tag it works correct. But the problem is I must know the aspect ratio of svg. I have the fixed height. So if I had known the aspect ratio I would know the width of svg anyway. If I knew the width I could change width auto  to  a fixed value. Thats why I asked a sperate question itself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260129/how-to-apply-width-auto-to-svg-in-edge-and-internet-explorer-11-browsers-withou

Comment: As far as I am aware, there isn't any other work-around.  If you need to handle different SVGs, then you would need to use some JS to read the `viewBox` and update the width and height each each SVG is loaded.